# How to setup Intellij idea terminal path with cmder but initiated with git bash.exe?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, git-bash, cmder

So I have installed both `Cmder` and `Git bash`, and my `Cmder` is setup in a way that to run git `bash.exe` inside.

Currently my Intellij idea's path for terminal is set to:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`, which works fine for `bash.exe`

However, one disadvantage for directly using `bash.exe` is that it will not automatically convert a windows directory, for example:
`D:\Documents\Adobe`, when I copy this after `cd`, it will be:

`cd D:\Documents\Adobe` instead of:

`cd /d/Documents/Adobe` which I will get in cmder.

I have looked up online, people shared about how to incorporate `cmder` in idea's terminal by using the path:

`"cmd.exe" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`

However, that is only using cmder as a coating for `cmd.exe`, not `bash.exe` as I want.

I have tried to replace with:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`, it was not working.

also tried:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`

and:

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" /k ""%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\init.bat""`

All failed.

Any sugestons? Thanks!
Or if someone can show me how to change git `bash.exe` so that it can automatically translate the windows directory to Linux type, that would also work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run git-bash in cmder AND from Intellij IDEA terminal.

I tried this: creating a task for git-bash in Cmder and try to use `cmder.exe /TASK xxx` in Intellij. I have the task, but it seems that Intellij does not support args after an executable in Terminal settings, so `/TASK xxx` is not parsable.

Then I changed path in Terminal settings to a BAT file, but terminal seems not support running it; I see terminal flashes and closes. Maybe only executable is allowed. Branch info is shown at the right of current path. I think it is convenient.

So, you have two options:

- change terminal to `git-bash.exe` and get used to slash as path separator(and that is much saner than back slashes, trust me)
- just configure Intellj Terminal to open cmder, with default task like this: `cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"  "`. This will open cmder in the current folder, and you also have git support. That is, stop using mingw64 and only ConEmu + clink. You have color support, Windows backslashes and so on. And you also can mix Win commands with bash syntax(with "Shell integration" ticked). This is what I am doing right now. Branch info is shown, lambda symbol as well. It is already perfect.

[image]